# How to zoom a PolarPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics

Let's say I'd like to have the unit circle to the border of this plot:

```
PolarPlot[1, {θ, -Pi, Pi}, 
  PolarAxes -> True, 
  PolarTicks -> {Automatic, Automatic}, 
  PolarGridLines -> {Automatic, Automatic}, 
  PlotRange -> 1.8]
```

PlotRange does not help zooming it, it just crops the graphics with the label. Have I missed something?

[image: polar plot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PolarAxesOrigin -> {π/2, 1}` is for that purpose:

```
PolarPlot[1, {θ, -π, π}, 
  PolarAxes -> True, 
  PolarAxesOrigin -> {π/2, 1}, 
  PolarTicks -> {Automatic, Automatic}, 
  PolarGridLines -> {Automatic, Automatic}, 
  PlotRange -> 1.1, 
  ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]